# Examples of surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I have to find an example of a surface of revolution excluding  a sphere and a cone.

Is $\sigma(x,y)=(\cos x, 5, x^2+y^2)$ such an example?

$$$$

I also have to find an example of a surface the image of which is not the graph of a smooth function $z=f(x,y)$.

Is $\sigma(x,y)=(3\sqrt{3}, 10\sqrt{y}, 0)$ such an example?

Comment: What surface do you imagine the first one is?  It maps the $x$-$y$ plane into a subset of the $x$-$z$ plane, doesn't it?  Or do I misunderstand your terminology?

Answer (score 1):

Take any curve $z=f(r)$. Then $z=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ will be a surface of revolution. The other question is unclear...

Comment: So is my first example correct?

Comment: My function $f:\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow \mathbb R$. Your example is $\sigma :\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow \mathbb R^3$, and thus the graph is in $\mathbb R^5$. But if it's considered as a prametrisation of a surface, then it's wrong...

Comment: I edited my initial post regarding the second question... Could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part:

The surface of revolution is parameterized as :

$(x, y, z) =  ( u \cos(v), u \sin(v), z= f(u) )$

u can be taken as any other smooth function g(u) also.

As you know for a cone

$$ u = z \tan (\alpha) ;\, z= u \cot (\alpha), $$

and sphere

$$ u = \sqrt{ 1-z^2} ;\,  z = \sqrt{ 1-u^2}, $$

it can be used for sweeping any meridian like a paraboloid of revolution here..

$$ u = \sqrt{ 4 f z } ; z = u^2/(4f)  $$

Is second question, like

$$ z = \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2} ? $$ .. did not understand question well.

Comment: So, is my first example wrong? I edited my initial post regarding the second question... Could you take a look at it?

Comment: I suppose both are wrong. First one must be in the form $ z= f(r) = f ( \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2} )$ ; For the second one there is the  Monge form $ z= f(x,y) $